# CompilerException: The input document is not a stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-fop

I am using fop for producing pdf output and I am new with that. After long hours of work I faced one problem:
*com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.CompilerException: The input document is not a stylesheet (the XSL namespace is not declared in the root element).*

There is my xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page">
                <fo:region-body margin="1in"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

                <!-- LOGO
                <fo:block>

                </fo:block>
                 -->

                <!-- TEXT -->
                <fo:block text-align="justify">
                    <xsl:value-of select="text" />
                </fo:block>

                <!-- TABLES -->
                <xsl:for-each select="./table">
                    <fo:block>
                        <fo:block font-weight="bold"> <!-- Add some adjustment -->
                            <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                        </fo:block>
                        <table> <!-- Add some border -->
                            <fo:table-body> <!-- Add some adjustment -->
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="./header/cell">
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                                <fo:block font-weight="bold"> <!-- Add some adjustment and extra border -->
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                                </fo:block>
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </fo:table-row>
                                <xsl:for-each select="./row">
                                    <fo:table-row>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="./cell">
                                            <fo:table-cell>
                                                <fo:block> <!-- Add some adjustment -->
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                                </fo:block>
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </fo:table-body>
                        </table>
                    </fo:block>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And Java part there printing file is triggered

```
private void convertToPDF(File xsl, File pdf) throws IOException,
        FOPException, TransformerException {

    FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();

    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(pdf));
    try {
        Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent,
                out);

        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(
                xsl));

        Source src = prepareSource();

        Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

        // Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
        transformer.transform(src, res);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Parameter xsl given to this method is file picked from my project resources and I am sure this is good file (printed it out).

My xml source is generated dynamically in java. If these files will be required, then I will edit this post and place them there.

I've been trying to edit my xsl file, simplify it but nothing worked.
For compilation I am using Eclipse with Spring Tool Suite extention.
Can You help me, please?

Also, can You tell me how to place image in my pdf output?

Comment: How do you run FOP? From the command line or from a Java program?

Comment: From Java. Just edited post, so it will be more noticable

Comment: Based on the error message it sounds as if you are not feeding an XSLT stylesheet to the XSLT processor. So make sure you are really feeding the code you posted as the XSLT stylesheet to the XSLT processor.

Comment: Could you show us the Java code where the XSLT is actually run, from the point where the XSLT is loaded to the time when it is executed?

Comment: Edited post, now there is java code. I am sure that this is correct file.

Comment: Noone knows? Shame...

Comment: possible duplicate of [xsltproc: document is not a stylesheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913295/xsltproc-document-is-not-a-stylesheet)